# How to list available web services?

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-services, reporting-services

How can I get a list of available webservices from a server/directory?

For example from:
http://localhost/ReportServer_SQL2008/

Which should at least give me 
ReportService2005.asmx

I was wondering if there wasn't a ReportService2008.asmx

Comment: Remove the localhost link and add snapshot of what you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following link may help you upto certain extent, which shows how to use UDDI at runtime :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms953948.aspx

If you are using WCF,then you can refer to :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zelmalki/archive/2008/12/15/create-dynamic-wcf-clients-without-any-configuration-service-references.aspx

Also, if you are using .NET4.0 ,then you can refer to the new WS Discovery feature in WCF at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456782.aspx